# Ionic Capacitor Device.getInfo() wait few minutes, but when plug usb is work fast

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, plugins, capacitor

I have an app developed with angular7

- Angular CLI: 7.3.8
- Node: 10.15.3
- OS: win32 x64
- Angular: 7.2.2
- ionic 4.12.0

In my app-component I call `await Device.getInfo()` (a Capacitor plugin) to know which platform of client we are on. In iOS it works good. But in Android there is very strange behavior. When  phone is not plugged to usb it take few minutes, but when if USB is connected, it works momentarily.

There is no some errors it just stuck and waiting.

I found this code capcitor repo: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/blob/master/core/src/web/device.ts

```
async getInfo(): Promise<DeviceInfo> {
    const ua = navigator.userAgent;
    const uaFields = this.parseUa(ua);
    let battery: any = {};

    try {
      battery = await navigator.getBattery();
    } catch (e) {
      // Let it fail, we don't care
    }

    return Promise.resolve({
      model: uaFields.model,
      platform: <'web'> 'web',
      appVersion: '',
      osVersion: uaFields.osVersion,
      manufacturer: navigator.vendor,
      isVirtual: false,
      batteryLevel: battery.level,
      isCharging: battery.charging,
      uuid: this.getUid()
    });
  }
```

Maybe it is important: Problem only when android phone run application in chrome http://localhost:4200 or http://server_ip:4200

Answer (score 0):

It's a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=999063) on Chrome 76 that makes getBattery take a long time if the device is not charging.
It has been [reported](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1913) on Capacitor repo too